# How to use Python to directly download a csv file which is exported through a submit button from a html form element?

Tags: python, html, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to write a script that pulls a .csv export file from a webpage through `beautifulsoup` directly into python without saving it locally but I am, admittedly, an extreme novice in this area.

The page in question allows you to search for matching records with various filters and gives you an option to download a .csv or excel file of the search results ([link](https://training.gov.au/Search?searchTitleOrCode=&SearchType=Rto&searchTgaSubmit=Search&registrationStatus=0%2C1%2C2%2C3&includeImplicitScope=true&scopeNationalCode=FNSACC601)).

My current attempts have been to use the **`requests.get()`** method with the below URL (that is generated on button click) but it just returns the page source code even though when pasted in the browser it triggers the file download.

```
https://training.gov.au/Search?id=po2ttdwopen4lfzbxekm42xk&exportSearchCsvSubmit=CSV&SearchType=Rto&searchTitleOrCode=&anzsco=&asced=&registrationStatus=0&registrationStatus=2&ScopeNationalCode=FNSACC602&IncludeImplicitScope'
```

I'm sure there's likely a simple explanation on why this behaviour is occuring... but I haven't been able to find a solution that doesn't include using selenium to download the file locally and access it that way.

Ultimately - I want to be able to pass through 1 or more **`ScopeNationalCode`** values and download the associated .csv results file directly in python without saving it locally. Right now I just want to know how to download the single file ([link](https://training.gov.au/Search?searchTitleOrCode=&SearchType=Rto&searchTgaSubmit=Search&registrationStatus=0%2C1%2C2%2C3&includeImplicitScope=true&scopeNationalCode=FNSACC601)) from the below webpage?

How can I get the .csv file directly in python without saving it to my local device first or is selenium the only solution?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre].

Comment: Without Selenium you probably have to examine the file for JavaScript and links to external JavaScript files to find the code which triggers the download (and the URL of the desired file).